# SSL HandshakeException for a HTTPS Get request

Tags: ssl, karate, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to set up a Karate framework for my project. I am getting the SSL handshake exception for the https call. But it's working fine if I change the protocol as Http.  I have tried to run with SSL =true, SSL = 'TLSv1.2' and I am getting a 404 error when I set up a proxy.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal error alert: handshake failure

Comment: ssl issues are impossible to solve remotely with limited info like this. I've linked a question that has some possible answers. if still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue